# Android Studio takes an hour to open the editor?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, amd-processor

Android Studio is taking around an hour just to open the Editor.
I understand people have been having issues running the emulator on AMD processors, but I am just starting the application here...?

My processor is an AMD Athlon II.
I use Android Studio at home on an i5 no problem, it takes a few seconds to open.

*It also takes around the same time to open Eclipse on this machine if it matters.

Any ideas why this takes so long, is it due to the processor?

Does android studio start an emulator as its initialized or anything like that?

Comment: how much ram do you have ? if eclipse takes the same time, I presume the problem resides in your system specification

Comment: android studio takes lots of space in ram so check your ram size

Comment: I have 8GB of RAM installed, I do have 16GB on the system that takes seconds as opposed to hours though. There are other people in the office that don't have the same issue and the only difference is they are using i5's

Comment: OK, It looks like the latest update may fix this, after almost 2 hours I got in only to install an update and wait another hour, after the latest update is applied it opens instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Android Studio seamlessly requires a 3.0-3.2 Ghz processor - Intel i5s are better and 8GB of RAM. This specification is enough for you to run Android Studio with its emulator's too.

AMD Athlon (dual core), more or less has the same GHz of processor speed compared to i5, but lags in virtual memory and number of processing threads with lower in L2 & L3 cache memory than Intel Core i5 processors. Also check whether you have enabled Intel VT/Virtual Technology (or similar which varies depending on the motherboard brands) in the BIOS.

i5 processors come in various generations (like 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and recently 5th gen), and different variants such as dual core,  quad core, octacore, etc. Android Studio works seamlessly in all the Core i5 processors (personally verified in some), but when it comes to hardware specs the higher the better.

That will do the trick to run Android Studio.

You can even open two windows in Android Studio with the aforementioned specs, thereby working in two projects at a time (i.e. multithreading).